# The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider<Object>'

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black87,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Ink.image(
              image: Image.asset('images/logo.png'), // here
            height: 100,
            width: 400,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want to apply asset image on my text button

Answer (score 2):

it wants image with ImageProvider type and you can change it with this

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: InkWell(
          splashColor: Colors.black87,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Ink.image(
              image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
            height: 100,
            width: 400,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: can you help me how to insert style in InkWell body?

Comment: InkWell doesn't have style component then you cannot use it

Comment: If you want to use style in it you can cover it's child with a Widget which has style component

Comment: can someone help me to insert asset image on my text button?

Comment: TextButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Image.asset("images/logo.png"))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AssetImage`

```dart
image:AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
```

Comment: can you help me to do the padding and center widget of text button, for example, i want it to look like category list view

Comment: are you trying to center and remove padding ? not sure about *category list view*

Comment: how to insert style: in InkWell widget? child: InkWell(
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.black,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
          ),
          splashColor: Colors.black87,
          onTap: () {},
          child: Ink.image(
              image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
            height: 100,
            width: 400,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),

Comment: Ok you are to override the style ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: InkWell(
    splashColor: Colors.black87,
    onTap: () {},
    child: Ink.image(
      image: AssetImage('images/logo.png'),
      height: 100,
      width: 400,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
),
```